# ScatterPlot and ONLY one Histogram plot together

Tags: r

I want to visualize time series data with a 'scatter plot' and a histogram on the right side, but I haven't been able to figure out how to turn OFF the histogram on the upper side.

Code Example:

```
install.packages("psych")
library(psych)
data = matrix(rnorm(n=100000,mean=2,sd=1.5), nrow = 100, ncol=1000)
fs = list()
fs$p_Z = 1*(data>2)
n_p = 1;
  for(i in floor(seq(1,dim(data)[2],length.out=n_p)))
{
  scatter.hist(x = rep(1:length(data[,i])), y = data[,i],
               xlab = 'observations',
               ylab = 'log(TPM)',
               title = 'Mixture Plot',
               col = c("red","blue")[fs$p_Z[,i]+1], 
               correl = FALSE, ellipse = FALSE, smooth = FALSE)
}
```

Result:

[image: scatter plot with two histograms, one upper side and one on right side]

Expected Result:
Same as the one I have but with no histogram on the upper side.  I.e., ONLY the histogram on the right side for log(TPM).

Note: I am using [psych package, scatter.hist function](https://personality-project.org/r/psych/help/scatter.hist.html) which seemed easy and nice to use, but couldn't find how to turn off one histogram.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where flexibility ends, hacking begins. If you look at `scatter.hist` function, you will see that it is pretty basic usage of R base graphics. Following modified code would create the plot you want:

```
scat.hist <- function(x, y, xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL, title = "", ...) {

## Create layout
layout(matrix(c(1,2),1,2,byrow=TRUE), c(3,1), c(1,3))

## Plot scatter
par(mar=c(5,5,3,1))
plot(x= x, y = y, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, main = title, ...)

## Right histogram
yhist <- hist(y, plot = FALSE, breaks = 11)
par(mar=c(5,2,3,1))
mp <- barplot(yhist$density, space=0, horiz=TRUE, axes = FALSE)
## Density
d <- density(y, na.rm = TRUE, bw = "nrd", adjust = 1.2)
temp <- d$y
        d$y <- (mp[length(mp)] - mp[1] + 1) * (d$x - min(yhist$breaks))/(max(yhist$breaks) - min(yhist$breaks))
        d$x <- temp
lines(d)
}
```

Let's try it for the first row:

```
i = 1
scat.hist(x = seq_along(data[,i]), y = data[,i], col = c("red", "blue")[fs$p_Z[,i]+1], xlab = 'observations', ylab = 'log(TPM)', title = 'Mixture Plot')
```

[image]